# SpamAssassin doesn't filter forwarded mails

Tags: email, spam, gmail, spamassassin, sieve

I am forwarding emails from an external email account to an account on my own server.
SpamAssassin works fine if I just receive mail normally. But all mail thats being forwarded from my external mail account to the server doesn't get filtered and ends up in my INBOX. So I end up with a bunch of SPAM.

Oddly, I tested all this and forwarded that same external email account to gmail and even Google didn't filter any of the obvious spam I was getting.

Any ideas what could be the culprit on this one?

Thanks in Advance.

```
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Score: 1.917
X-Spam-Level: *
X-Spam-Status: No, score=1.917 tagged_above=-999 required=5
```

Comment: Posting the headers of a spam message that got through would probably help. I've never administered SpamAssassin myself, but I know that details of how SpamAssassin scores its spam shows up in the headers. This and some other info in there might be useful to have in your question.

Comment: Good point. I will get to it as soon as I am back at my computer.

Comment: It's depends on how SA processed the messages and how it is integrated with MTA/LDA

Answer (score 0):

So turns out after looking at the Email Header. That spamassassin did check the email but simply didn't consider it SPAM.

Therefore I had to fix my spamassassin configuration and everything is working fine again.

Take away is: Always check the email headers first.